# Inserting a link to header for code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

New to code igniter. I need to insert a link to go to our blog site. I found the line in the header.php file and not sure to insert the link.

```
          <li class="gnb"><a class="mn-stores" href="blogs"><?php echo "Blogs";?></a></li>
```

Comment: Change the href attributes to your blog site url

Comment: so it would look like this?             <li class="gnb"><a class="mn-stores" href="blogs"><?php echo "Blogs";?></a></li>

Comment: sorry
so it would look like this

Comment: <li class="gnb"><a class="mn-stores" href="www.myblog.html"><?php echo "Blogs";?></a></li>  : If it works, I'll rewrite my comment as an answer so you can close the question

Comment: <li class="gnb"><a class="mn-stores" href="[link](http://blog.designtrades.org)"><?php echo "Blogs";?></a></li>

Comment: Not sure if what I put was what you meant but still did not work

Comment: the blog is actually on a sub domain like blog.designtrades.org and after inserting this in the href I still get a 404 error that page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the href attribute with your blog URL.

In your case, it should look like this :

Here's some doc from [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a)

```
<li class="gnb"><a class="mn-stores" href="http://blog.designtrades.org/"><?php echo "Blogs";?></a></li>
```

By clicking on ''Blogs'' , it should redirect to your blog. If that is not what you asked for, I don't understand the question, sorry

Comment: Thanks. I placed this exactly like this and it still is not directed to the URL but get a 404 error

Comment: was not sure if this also needs to changed also somewhere like a controller or class?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this instead,

```
<a class="mn-stores" href="http://blog.designtrades.org/" target="_blank">Blogs</a>
```

if it is not working, can you please provide the url of the page where you are receiving a 404 error. Thank you.

Comment: I tried replacing with the above and got the same.Here is the url of the page where I get the 404 error

Answer (score 0):

When you need to go to link auto load the [url helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=anchor#url-helper)

```
<li class="gnb">
<a class="mn-stores" href="<?php echo base_url('blog');?>">Blogs</a>
</li>
```

With codeIgniter anchor

```
<li class="gnb">
<?php echo anchor('blog', array('class' => 'mn-stores'));?>
</li>
```

You may need to configure your routes on application/config/routes.php

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

And in codeigniter 3 versions it is recommend that you set a base url.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

Another thing is good is codeigniter anchor with the [url helper / anchor](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=anchor#anchor)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help but I tried all of this and keep getting the 404 error. Not sure what to do at this point. Is it causing a problem that I am linking this to a sub-domain blog.designtrades.org?

Comment: the URL is http://designtrades.org/blogs but want the link to go to the sub-domain

Comment: @user1454418 you did not say that I thought it was a main domain. Try with setting your base url `$config['base_url'] = 'http://blog.example.com/';`